# Contact name retrieval returns "Skype video call"

Tags: android

I'm using the below code:

```
int indexContactId = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);

/*......*/

 int id = Integer.parseInt(people.getString(indexContactId));
 Cursor name_cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "  = " + id, null, null);

 String first_name = "";
 String last_name = "";
 while (name_cursor.moveToNext()) {
     if (name_cursor.getString(name_cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME)) != null) {
         first_name = name_cursor.getString(name_cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
         last_name = name_cursor.getString(name_cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
    }
 }
 name_cursor.close();
```

to get the first and last name of the contact (separately).

Alongside this, I'm also retrieving the DISPLAY_NAME

```
int indexName = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

The problem is that for some of the contacts, I get values like:

- DISPLAY_NAME: Franck MILEN
- FAMILY_NAME: 0
- GIVEN_NAME: Skype video
  call

What's going on with the Skype call thing ? And how can I retrieve the proper MILEN name ? Or at least know to ignore these, as Franck MILEN is also returned with proper names.

**EDIT**

What I need is a better way to get the `first_name`, `last_name`, and `phone_number` of a user (first and last name should be separate) and not get or ignore the Skype video call things :)

Comment: What is that you want to achieve?  Fetch the display name of all the contacts on your phone ?

Comment: Yes, and also the phone numbers. But I need the name to be separated, so I set them in a list with sticky headers (the headers being initials). And the problem I'm having is that I'm displaying the DISPLAY_NAME in the list, but using the first letter from GIVEN_NAME as the header initial. And it displays "Franck MILEN" under "S" :)

Comment: In short you need the display_name, given_name, phone_number of each contact?

Comment: I need the first_name, last_name, phone_number ... and stop it from showing the Skype things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I need to answer my own question. Here's the code I'm using, and it seems to work, it doesn't return the Skype contacts anymore:

```
                int id = Integer.parseInt(people.getString(indexContactId));

            String[] projectionNames = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, ContactsContract.Data.DATA3};
            String where = ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "  = " + id
                    + " AND "
                    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";
            Uri uriNames = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

            Cursor name_cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(uriNames, projectionNames, where, null, null);

            String first_name = "";
            String last_name = "";
            while (name_cursor.moveToNext()) {
                first_name = name_cursor.getString(name_cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2));
                last_name = name_cursor.getString(name_cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3));
            }
            name_cursor.close();
            name_cursor = null;
```